# Ignoring identity column when passing value to a table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to pass values to a table-valued parameter of a stored procedure like this:

```
DataTable Entries = new DataTable();
Entries.Columns.Add("InfoID", typeof (int));
Entries.Columns.Add("InfoValue", typeof (string));
foreach(FormInfoValue entry in FormEntries) {
    Entries.Rows.Add(entry.InfoID, entry.InfoValue);
}
DataSet res = ExecuteStoredProcedure("SaveData", new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter() {
        DbType = DbType.String, ParameterName = "@FormID", Value = FormID
    },
    new SqlParameter() {
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, ParameterName = "@InfoValues", Value = Entries
    },
    new SqlParameter() {
        DbType = DbType.Int32, ParameterName = "@UserID", Value = Security.SessionControl.GetSession().UserID
    }
});
return int.Parse(res.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

But the problem is that the Table-valued parameter `@InfoValues` has one extra column that is identity. I am using that column in my logic in stored procedure. But at C# its throwing exception of having 3 columns instead of 2 in `@InfoValues`. How can I pass values by ignoring identity column in this table-valued parameter?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use a temp table as a solution like this:

```
DECLARE @FormData TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    InfoID INT NULL,
    InfoValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
    )
INSERT INTO @FormData(InfoID,InfoValue) SELECT [InfoID],[InfoValue] FROM @InfoValues
        WHILE (1 = 1)
        BEGIN
            EXEC [dbo].OpenKeys
            SELECT TOP 1 @iid = [ID], @id = InfoID, @value = InfoValue FROM @FormData WHERE [ID] > @iid ORDER BY [ID]
            -- Exit loop if no more info values
            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;

            INSERT INTO [InfoValues]([InfoID],[Value],[UserID],[DateAdded],[DateUpdated]) 
            VALUES(@id,[dbo].ENCRYPTDATA(@value),@UserID,GETDATE(), GETDATE()); 
            SET @retID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
            INSERT INTO EVMap(EntryID, ValueID) VALUES(@EntryID, @retID)
        END
```

Is this approach efficient?

Comment: Why not change your procedure to use ROW_NUMBER instead of an identity?

Comment: @SeanLange For that I think I need to change a lot of code. Can I use a temporary table instead that contains primary key? First insert the data into that temporary table and then use it in the processing?

Comment: That is a possibility. It is hard to say what is the best/easiest way without knowing what your procedure does though.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated my question with stored procedure code. Have a look.

Comment: As I understand it the only reason you need that ID is to keep track of your loop? If so you might be better off using a cursor, then that ID isn't needed.

Comment: @Chris I don't know much about cursors. Can you please give me a code example or modify my code?

Comment: You don't need a loop here at all to be honest. Not sure what that OpenKeys proc is doing or why you need it every iteration of your loop. It would possibly take some effort though to convert this to a set based solution because it looks like you some sort of scalar function for encryption. Changing that function up would make this simple with an insert and using the OUTPUT clause.

Comment: I am unable to form a query without loop. Openkeys can be called outside loop but the last insertion to EVMap must be called for every inserted element to InfoValues. @SeanLange

Comment: That does NOT mean you need a loop. The OUTPUT clause can send the identity to another table. That is one of the most useful aspects of that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: Its quite a big topic and google will probably tell you all you need to know. The summary though is a cursor will loop over a recordset and put each row into variables that you can then use in whatever way you want. At a glance you seem to be wanting a CURSOR here and recreating it as best you could with what you knew about. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 is one page dealing with the basic syntax.

Comment: @Chris a cursor is NOT the best choice here. This can be done set based using OUTPUT.

Comment: @SeanLange: I'm happy to believe that without looking too much into it. My initial comment was just because I saw that what was being done looked like it would be done better as a cursor. I didn't really look into whether it could be done a better way. My followup comment just now was just because its worth knowing what a cursor is, even if its not the best solution here. :)

Comment: LOL I would agree that knowing about cursors is important so that you can find a way to eradicate them. They are extremely helpful in certain situations but most of the time they are used when a set based approach would be better both for simplicity and performance.

Comment: @SeanLange: Yeah, I do recall once being told "Never use cursors" now you mention it. I'm a c# developer though rather than a SQL developer. I'm the kind of person that probably winds up SQL developers with my occasional desire to treat SQL like its a programming language (and thus use loops and things). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I of course can't test this but it at least parses. Here is an example of how this might look using `OUTPUT` instead of looping. This assume that some of the variable are already defined and you receive `@InfoValues` as a table valued parameter.

```sql
EXEC [dbo].OpenKeys

INSERT INTO [InfoValues]
(
    [InfoID]
    , [Value]
    , [UserID]
    , [DateAdded]
    , [DateUpdated]
) 
OUTPUT @EntryID      -- I assume this is set somewhere else in your code
    , INSERTED.RetID -- or whatever column is your identity in InfoValues
INTO EVMap(EntryID, ValueID)
SELECT InfoID
    , [dbo].ENCRYPTDATA(InfoValue)
    , @UserID -- I assume this is set somewhere else in your code
    , GETDATE()
    , GETDATE()
FROM @InfoValues
```

Comment: Thanks a alot @SeanLange. You are a lifesaver. :)